# Scp command syntax for copying a folder from local machine to a remote server

Tags: linux, scp, putty

I am using putty for copying files from local machine to remote server.My folder is in `C:/site`
can any one give syntax for copying folder from `C:/site` to remote server using `scp`

Comment: id is the login ID you use for the server, server = ip address.

Comment: if i want to copy in folder how i can specify the folder

Comment: append `:path` after the ip. See my answer (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In stall PuTTY in our system and set the environment variable PATH Pointing to putty path.
open the command prompt and move to putty folder. Using PSCP command

[Please check this](ftp://ftp.zedat.fu-berlin.de/pc/network/putty/putty-0.55/htmldoc/Chapter5.html)

Answer (score 82):

```
scp -r C:/site user@server_ip:path
```

`path` is the place, where `site` will be copied into the remote server

---

**EDIT**: As I said in my comment, try `pscp`, as you want to use `scp` using `PuTTY`.

The other option is [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

Comment: am getting an error 'C:Temporary failure in name resolution'

Comment: Can you paste here the whole command, that you use (without user/pass, put *** in their place (: )

Comment: scp -r C:/site *****@$$$$$: /var/www/newfolder

Comment: @THOmas - remove the space after `:`. It must be: `scp -r C:/site *****@$$$$$:/var/www/newfolder`

Comment: try `ls -la C:/site` to see if this will show something or this location does not exiests. What is you OS? Looks like `unix` base to me, because of the slash ( `/` ), but if so, you don't have `C:/` in linux.

Comment: My os is windows xp and am using putty

Comment: I think you should use WinSCP (http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) and I'm not sure, that PuTTY can do this.

Comment: Thank Kiril Kirov.. I have used winscp for copying files ..I am trying to use Putty... :)

Comment: OOh, I get it. OK then, change `scp` to `pscp` and try again. If this don't work, I can't help you anymore, as I have used PuTTY very little.